# What book is this CCNA lab exercise from?

Tags: cisco

I am studying hard for my ‎100-101 ICND1 exam, and a big part of that effort is using GNS3 to mock up lab scenarios so I can get my hands dirty configuring routers and switches* manually.

One thing I'm finding a lack of is good lab scenarios to use. I did find this PDF, and it appears to be part of a larger manual for the Cisco Network Academy: [Lab 9.6.1: Basic EIGRP Configuration Lab](http://www.chipps.com/2/Lab9-1.pdf). This is exactly the type of thing I am looking for, and I was hoping someone would recognize it and tell me what the exact title is and if it is generally available for purchase without having to enroll. I am more than willing to pay for this resource, but the Cisco Network Academy site is less than obvious about what I have to do in order to get access to just the book.

*I am aware of the common misconception that GNS3 can't emulate L2 switches. I was of that same view until recently, when the GNS3 support folks told me about IOU. I can now simultaneously run router devices and switch devices in GNS3 and practice all my R/S config skills in a native environment.*

Comment: Actually, product and/or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation. I'm asking for someone to help identify this resource, which I have already identified as something I would like to purchase.

Comment: @JeffWright can you come to the  [General Network Engineering recommendations chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations) ? I have some answer for you ;)

Comment: It is from the Cisco Networking Academy. Then I don't understand your question. You attend classes, and it is included in the materials you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of the manual is "Routing Protocols and Concepts - CCNA Exploration Labs and Study Guide."

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase the Cisco Networking Academy course and lab books at bookstores. A simple Internet search will turn up many sources for the materials.